# como buscar objetos y quitarlos del array

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

//hola buenas tardes, les cuento lo que quiero hacer, estoy tratando de hacer un sistema de seguidores, quiero traer usuarios para que alguien los siga pero no quiero traer a los que ya estan seguidos, mi idea es buscar los usuarios y tambien los usuarios seguidos y compararlos, si existen dos id iguales en cada collecion quitarlos

```
 var usuarios = await newUser.find({_id: {$ne: usuario}}); //aqui traigo todos los usuarios distintos a mi id
 var usuariosSeguidos = await seguimiento.find({usuario: {$ne: usuario}});  //aqui traigo los que no son seguidos por el usuario
```

como puedo hacer para crear un arrays y que dentro de objetos queden solo los usuarios que no sigue el usuario?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes emplear un aggregation para realizar la operación. Con [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/), obtienes por un lado los usuarios que sigues, y por otro lado todos los usuarios menos tú. Después aplicas la [$setDifference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/index.html) para saber que usuarios no estás siguiendo.

```
db.usuarios.aggregate([
        {
            $facet: {
                usuariosSeguidos: [
                    {
                        $match: {
                            _id: usuarioId
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $lookup: {
                            from: 'seguimiento',
                            localField: '_id',
                            foreignField: 'usuario',
                            as: 'usuariosSeguidos'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $unwind: '$usuariosSeguidos'
                    },
                    {
                        $replaceRoot: { newRoot: { $mergeObjects: [ '$usuariosSeguidos'] } }
                    },
                    {
                        $project: {
                            _id: 0,
                            usuarioId: '$usuario'
                        }
                    }
                ],
                usuarios: [
                    {
                        $match: {
                            _id: { $ne: usuarioId }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        $project: {
                            _id: 0,
                            usuarioId: '$_id'
                        }
                    },
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            $project: {
                usuariosQueNoSigo: {
                    $setDifference: ['$usuariosSeguidos', '$usuarios']
                }
            }
        }
])
```

Comment: te agradezco que hayas respondido, no me quedo muy en claro que es lo que hace tu consulta, me la podrias compilar a lenguaje humano jaja un pequeño chiste, en fin, te agradeceria si me orientaras mas con el codigo que me facilitaste

Comment: Lo que hace la consulta es esta operación:

**Usuarios que no sigo = (Todos los usuarios - yo) - usuarios que yo sigo**

Con $facet podemos realizar varias consultas en un mismo aggregate.