# metodo AGGREGATE con mongodb

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

//hola a todos, les cuento brevemente lo que intento hacer, quiero hacer un sistema de seguidores, lo que intento hacer es obtener los usuarios que sigo, los que no y todos los usuarios, de esa manera crear un array con todos los usuarios menos los que sigo incluyendome a mi obvio por que no puedo seguirme a mi mismo, me explico?
dejo una pequeña parte del código

```
import Follow, {IUfollow} from '../models/follow'
import User, { IUser } from '../models/User'



export const userFollows = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  if (!req.userId) return res.status(401).json({error: "No tienes autorizacion para realizar dicha peticion al servidor."})
  let seguidos = await Follow.find({seguidor: req.userId}) //aca obtengo todos los usuarios que estos siguiendo
  let seguidores = await Follow.find({seguidos: req.userId}) //aca obtengo todos los seguidores mios
  let usuarios = await User.find({_id: {$ne: req.userId}}) //aca obtengo todos los usuarios menos yo 

}
```

//me sugirieron implementar un agreggate pero en verdad en la documentación de mongoDB no logro entenderlo

//aqui abajo agrego mis `models`

**modelo de usuarios**

```
import { Schema, model, Document } from 'mongoose'
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

export interface IUser extends Document {
   nombre: string;
   apellido: string;
   username: string;
   email: string;
   birth: string;
   sexo: string;
   password: string;
   encrypPassword(password: string): Promise<string>;
   validatePassword(password: string): Promise<boolean>;
};

const userSchema = new Schema({
nombre: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
apellido: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
},
birth: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
},
perfil: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default: 'avatar-default.png'
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
}
}, {
   timestamps: true
});
```

**y aqui el modelo de follows**

```
import { Schema, model, Document } from 'mongoose'

export interface IUfollow extends Document {
   seguidor: string;
   seguido: string;
};

const followsSchema = new Schema({
   seguidor: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
   },
   seguido: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
   }

}, {
  timestamps: true
});


export default model<IUfollow>('follows', followsSchema);
```

/esos son mis modelos de usuarios y de follows

Comment: Para implementar procesos de agregación, no es la documentación de Mongoose la que debes leer, al contrario, debes leer la documentación de [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/index.html) sobre agregación. Si colocas el código de tus modelos `Follow` y `User` y algún ejemplo de lo que intentas hacer, con gusto te doy una mano. Saludos

Comment: ya lo eh agregado, me vendria de maravilla tu ayuda, muchisimas gracias

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [mostrar usuarios con los que se tiene una conversación y su ultimo mensaje](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/342743/mostrar-usuarios-con-los-que-se-tiene-una-conversaci%c3%b3n-y-su-ultimo-mensaje)

Comment: Esta pregunta la planteaste ya en este otro post https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/342743/mostrar-usuarios-con-los-que-se-tiene-una-conversaci%C3%B3n-y-su-ultimo-mensaje/342817 en el que respondí el aggregate de como obtener los usuarios que no sigues. Si no entiendes bien edito la respuesta de manera más clara para que comprendas lo que hace

Comment: por favor, llevo semanas metido en este problema y debo tenerlo listo para dentro de una sema, ya no se donde buscar solucion

Comment: Estoy en ello, aunque @GUDARI mencionó que te había dado una respuesta, pero me temo que o no es lo que buscas o simplemente no lo entiendes.

Comment: Recuerdo que hablamos por el chat y te preparé el ejemplo con la explicación. SI no entiendes algo por favor indícalo en los comentarios y hablamos por el chat del otro post y te explico detenidamente como funciona el aggregate y porqué está así. un saludo

Comment: bien,estasmezclando dos preguntas, una a la cual ya pude solucuionar que es la del chat, esto es otra cosa

Comment: Vale perdon me confundí de pregunta, pero si que es una que ya hiciste y te respondí como solucionarlo https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/335332/como-buscar-objetos-y-quitarlos-del-array/335556#335556

Comment: exacto, fue una respuesta a la cual no pude entenderla, simplemente escribiste una solución a mi problema que no diste a explicar y desafortunadamente fue en vano ya que no fue una solucion al menos para mi

Answer (score 1):

tldr;

**PROBLEMA**

Uno de los problemas que encuentro en tu modelo de datos es que no es para nada práctico, y aunque esta es un opinión debatible, hay criterios en los que puedo apoyar mi punto de vista.

Deseas tener un sistema de [*followers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friending_and_following), y poder realizar un reporte sobre el mismo. Necesitas dividir el reporte en 3 tipos:

1. Todos los usuarios
2. Todos los usuarios a los que sigo
3. Todos los usuarios que no sigo

Este último reporte es simplemente el complemento del conjunto representado en el apartado 2.

**SOLUCIÓN**

La solución parte de realizar las modificaciones pertinentes en tus modelos de datos.

Vamos a ver 2 formas de hacerlo (puede haber otras formas además de las que planteo aquí).

**Creando una lista *following* dentro del modelo de Usuario**

MongoDB es muy flexible, y nos permite anidar documentos y crear documentos complejos con diferentes tipos de datos. Usando esta característica, crearemos el sistema de seguidores simplemente usando una lista como campo dentro del documento de usuario.

Supongamos un modelo básico llamado `User`, el cual entre sus propiedades tendrá un campo llamado `following` o `siguiendo` (si lo prefieres en castellano). Tomando parte de tu modelo de usuario crearé este modelo de la siguiente forma:

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // campos que desees agregar
  // ...
  following: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    }
  ],
  // ...
});

export default mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

En el código anterior hemos definido un campo `following` de tipo `Array` y hemos indicado que el mismo contendrá un objeto de tipo `ObjecId` y que hace referencia a algún documento de la colección de usuarios.

Esto es todo el cambio en nuestro modelo, y como vemos es bastante simple. Y no necesito crear o usar otro modelo de datos para mi sistema de seguidores.

¿Cómo genero los reportes? Bueno, esta parte es un poco más amplia. Existen muchas formas de generarlos. Iremos por paso.

**1. Todos los usuarios**

Para obtener la lista de todos los usuarios, usaremos el método `find()` de nuestro modelo.

```
User.find({})
  .then(users => {
    console.log(users);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error.message);
  });
```

Simple, sin usar `aggregate` ni cosas complicadas. Si queremos evitar ciertos campos, podemos pasar un objeto con opciones (proyección) a nuestra consulta. Supongamos que sólo nos interesa devolver el campo `username` y el campo `email` (además del campo `_id`):

```
User.find({}, {username: 1, email: 1}) // devolvemos sólo los campos email y username
  .then(...)
  .catch(...);
```

**2. Todos los usuarios a los que sigo**

Ahora, [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/) nos provee una forma de devolver los usuarios de nuestra lista de `following` a la cual hemos ido incorporando los usuarios a los que estamos siguiendo. El método en Mongoose es [`populate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate_multiple_documents), y nos traerá la información que solicitemos de cada usuario en la lista `following`. Ahora, tal vez nos interese traer todos los datos de dichos usuarios o tal vez sólo nos interesen algunos campos, veremos cómo hacer ambas cosas a la vez.

Supongamos que tenemos el siguiente documento:

```js
{
  "following": [
    "5e9af75782b4212fc42c4b0c",
    "5e9af77182b4212fc42c4b0e",
    "5e9af7a582b4212fc42c4b0f",
    "5e9af7da82b4212fc42c4b10",
    "5e9af80c82b4212fc42c4b11",
    "5e9af82582b4212fc42c4b12",
    "5e9af85982b4212fc42c4b13",
    "5e9af91c82b4212fc42c4b19"
  ],
  "_id": "5e9aeade82b4212fc42c4b0b",
  "nombre": "Sansa",
  "apellidos": "Stark",
  "email": "sansa@stark.com",
  "__v": 1
}
```

El usuario *Sansa Stark* tiene una lista de `following`, la cual se compone exclusivamente de elementos de tipo `ObjectId` que apuntan a documentos de tipo `User` de otros usuarios de la colección. El siguiente método trae todos los documentos de usuario referenciados en 'following' para el usuario *Sansa Stark*:

```js
User.findById(id)
  .populate({ path: 'following' })
  .exec((error, results) => {
    //lógica para manejar los resultados
  });
```

El resultado del método anterior es un documento con un campo único llamado `following` que es una lista de documentos de usuario, que se corresponden con los usuarios a los que sigue *Sansa*:

```js
{
  "following": [
    {
      "following": [
         //lista de usuarios a los que sigue
       ],
       "_id": "5e9af75782b4212fc42c4b0c",
       "nombre": "Arya",
       "apellidos": "Stark",
       "email": "arya@stark.com",
       "__v": 1
     },
     {
       "following": [
         // lista de usuarios a los que sigue
       ],
       "_id": "5e9af77182b4212fc42c4b0e",
       "nombre": "Eddard",
       "apellidos": "Stark",
       "email": "eddard@stark.com",
       "__v": 1
      },
      // ...
      {
        "following": [],
        "_id": "5e9af91c82b4212fc42c4b19",
        "nombre": "Joffrey",
        "apellidos": "Baratheon",
        "email": "joffrey@baratheon.com",
        "__v": 0
      }
   ]
}
```

Ahora, cada documento es el documento completo, es decir, incluye todos sus campos, y entre ellos, el campo `following` de cada usuario. Supongamos que sólo nos interesa ver el nombre, apellido y correo, podemos usar la siguiente consulta que le indica al método `populate()` los campos que debe retornar.

Usando `select: '<nombres de campos separados por espacio>'`, por ejemplo:

```js
User.findById(id)
.populate({ path: 'following', select: 'nombre apellido email' })
.exec((error, result) => {
  // lógica para manejar el resultado
});
```

O bien usando `select: {<nombre de campo>: <1 o 0>, ...}`, donde `1` indica que se debe traer el campo y 0 indica que no. El campo `_id` siempre se trae, a menos que se indique explícitamente con `0`. Por ejemplo:

```js
User
.findById(req.profile._id)
.populate({ path: 'following', select: {nombre: 1, apellidos: 1, email: 1} })
.exec((error, result) => {
  // lógica para manejar el resultado
});
```

Ambas instrucciones anteriores nos darán el siguiente resultado:

```js
{
  "following": [
    {
      "_id": "5e9af75782b4212fc42c4b0c",
      "nombre": "Arya",
      "apellidos": "Stark",
      "email": "arya@stark.com"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e9af77182b4212fc42c4b0e",
      "nombre": "Eddard",
      "apellidos": "Stark",
      "email": "eddard@stark.com"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5e9af7a582b4212fc42c4b0f",
      "nombre": "Robb",
      "apellidos": "Stark",
      "email": "robb@stark.com"
    },
    // ...
    {
      "_id": "5e9af91c82b4212fc42c4b19",
      "nombre": "Joffrey",
      "apellidos": "Baratheon",
      "email": "joffrey@baratheon.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

No se deben mezclar `0`'s y `1`'s, excepto cuando se evita explícitamente el campo `_id`. La siguientes opciones son inválidas:

```
select: {nombre: 1, apellidos: 0, correo: 1}
select: {nombre: 0, apellidos: 0, correo: 1}
```

Para mayor información consultar la [documentación](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select).

**3. Usuarios a los que no sigo**

Esta es la consulta que parece que tiene el mayor desafío. Necesitamos la lista de usuarios a los que no sigo.

Una forma de traer este resultado sin usar un método de agregación sería realizar 2 consultas. La primera consulta me sirve para conocer la lista de los usuarios a los que sigo, la segunda consulta me sirve para traer a todos los usuarios a los que no sigo, basándome en la lista que obtuve de la consulta anterior.

Veamos un ejemplo:

```js
User.findById(id)
.populate({path: 'following', select: { _id: 1 }}) // sólo me interesa el campo _id
.exec((error, result) => {
  if(error) {// lógica para el caso de error}
  let exclude = [ id ];  // lista de id's por excluir (incluyo el mio)
  result.following.forEach(user => { // recorremos el array de objetos
    exclude.push(user._id); // añadimos cada id a la lista
  });
  // Ahora podemos consultar a la DB todos los usuarios, menos los de la lista 'exclude'
  User.find({ _id: {$nin: exclude} }, (error, users) => {
    // lógica para manejar el resultado
  });
});
```

En esta segunda consulta he utilizado el operador de consulta [`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/#op._S_nin) de [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/). Recordemos que Mongoose es un ODM que se basa (o usa) el driver oficial de MongoDB para NodeJS, por lo tanto, casi todos los operadores de consulta disponibles en MongoDB están disponibles para NodeJS y por lo tanto para Mongoose.

Con esto ya tienes resueltas las 3 consultas que necesitabas sin usar un método de agregación.

Cabe destacar que la cosnulta se hace sobre un usuario particular, por ende el mismo no aparece en ninguna de las 2 últimas listas, simplemente porque no tiene sentido incluirlo en ninguna de ellas.

**Creando una colección de *followers***

Viendo que en tu modelo de datos tienes una colección para *followers*, usaremos esta aproximación, pero no sin antes hacer un cambio en el modelo de datos, ya que me parece que podemos mejorar un poco la presentación de los mismos.

Tienes un modelo que se compone de 2 atributos: `seguidor` y `seguido`, esto hace que tengas repetición de datos. Si *Sansa Stark* sigue a 8 usuarios, entonces habrá 8 documentos diferentes en la colección `followers` para *Sansa Stark*, y cada vez que *Sansa* añada a un usuario a su lista de seguidos, se generará 1 nuevo documento. Esto explota mi mente en cuanto a organización. Y es que si esto fuese un archivador físico (imagina que la colección `followers` es un estante o cajón), cada vez que *Sansa* decide seguir a un usuario, se agrega una carpeta al estante, cuyo contenido es una *única* hoja con la ficha del usuario al que sigue. Qué desperdicio de carpetas o espacio en el cajón o estante. ¿No sería mejor, tener 1 sóla carpeta que contenga varias fichas de usuarios a los que *Sansa* sigue?

Pues eso es lo que intentaremos, y verás que los métodos son básicamente los mismos.

Tu modelo de `Follower` podría ser resscrito así:

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const FollowerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  follower: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
    required: ['El campo \'seguidor\' es necesario']
    unique: true
  },
  following: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User',
    }
  ]
});

export default mongoose.model('Follower', FollowerSchema);
```

Y con esto tenemos una colección en la que todos sus campos son referencias a la colección de usuarios.

Veamos cómo traer los datos que requerimos consultando a la colección `followers`.

Dependiendo de la lógica de nuestro programa o aplicación puedo tener 2 posibilidades:

- Cada vez que se agrega un usuario nuevo, se añade a la lista de `followers` independientemente si el usuario sigue o no sigue a otro usuario.
- Se añade un usuario existente a la lista de `followers` sólo cuando el mismo comienza a seguir a al menos 1 usuario.

Como podemos ver son 2 aproximaciones diferentes. Vamos a asumir la segunda, ya que tiene más sentido cuando se trata de separación de responsabilidades.

Sin embargo debemos tomar la precaución siguiente:

- Cada documento de la colección `followers` tendrá su propio campo `_id`.
- El campo `_id` de un documento de la colección `followers` no es igual al campo `_id` del usuario de la colección `users`.

Teniendo eso en cuenta, supongamos que tenemos el siguiente documento en nuestra colección `followers`:

```js
{
  "following": [
    "5e9af8c882b4212fc42c4b16",
    "5e9af90b82b4212fc42c4b18",
    "5e9af91c82b4212fc42c4b19",
    "5e9af93982b4212fc42c4b1a",
    "5e9af95682b4212fc42c4b1b",
    "5e9af8a382b4212fc42c4b14"
  ],
  "_id": "5e9b4001decc20612f3a2a27",
  "follower": "5e9af8b982b4212fc42c4b15",
  "__v": 0
}
```

A simple vista no sabemos nada de los documentos a los que apunta cada `ObjectId`, asi que esta información no es muy útil. Esta información la obtenemos de la siguiente consulta:

```js
Followers.find({}, (error, followers) => {
  // followers será una lista (array) de documentos como el que se decribe con anterioridad
});
```

Pero si cambiamos la consulta anterior por la siguiente:

```js
Followers
.find({})
.populate({ path: 'follower', select: 'nombre apellidos email' })
.exec((error, followers) => {
  // Lógica para manejar el resultado
});
```

El resultado de la consulta anterior, podría verse como sigue:

```js
{
  "following": [
    "5e9af8c882b4212fc42c4b16",
    "5e9af90b82b4212fc42c4b18",
    "5e9af91c82b4212fc42c4b19",
    "5e9af93982b4212fc42c4b1a",
    "5e9af95682b4212fc42c4b1b",
    "5e9af8a382b4212fc42c4b14"
  ],
  "_id": "5e9b4001decc20612f3a2a27",
  "follower": {
    "_id": "5e9af8b982b4212fc42c4b15",
    "nombre": "Cersei",
    "apellidos": "Lannister",
    "email": "cersei@lannister.com"
  },
  "__v": 0
}
```

Claramente se aprecia que el documento contiene toda la información solicitada del usuario referenciado en `follower`. En este caso, *Cersei Lannister* es la `follower` de 6 usuarios diferentes de nuestra colección de usuarios.

**1. Todos los usuarios**

Esta consulta es igual que la del caso anterior:

```
User.find({}, callback);
```

Sin embargo, si deseo la lista de usuarios que siguen al menos a otro usuario, la misma la haría sobre el modelo `Follower`:

```
Follower.find({}, callback);
```

Si deseo los datos del `follower`, como vimos antes usamos `populate()` sobre el campo adecuado.

**2. Todos los usuarios a los que sigo**

Ahora, tenemos 2 formas de consultar la colección de `followers`, usando el `_id` del documento en cuestión, o usando el `_id` del usuario en cuestion. Usaremos la segunda opción, ya que es más lógico pensar en el resultado en términos del `_id` del usuario.

```js
Follower
.findOne({ follower: id })
.populate({ path: 'follower', select: 'nombre apellidos email' }, callback);
```

Hemos usado el método [`findOne()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) de Mongoose y como consulta le hemos indicado que nos devuelva el documento cuyo campo `follower` coincida con el `id` que pasamos por referencia, el cual se refiere al campo `_id` de nuestro usuario.

Hasta aquí todo correcto, pero necesitamos los datos de los usuarios a los que seguimos, asi que en vez de hacer `populate` sobre el campo `follower`, lo haremos sobre el campo `following`:

```js
Follower
.findOne({ follower: id })
.populate({ path: 'following', select: 'nombre apellidos email' }, callback);
```

El resultado se podría ver parecido al siguiente:

```js
"following": [
  {
      "_id": "5e9af8c882b4212fc42c4b16",
      "nombre": "Jaime",
      "apellidos": "Lannister",
      "email": "jaime@lannister.com"
  },
  {
      "_id": "5e9af90b82b4212fc42c4b18",
      "nombre": "Robert",
      "apellidos": "Baratheon",
      "email": "robert@baratheon.com"
  },
  {
      "_id": "5e9af91c82b4212fc42c4b19",
      "nombre": "Joffrey",
      "apellidos": "Baratheon",
      "email": "joffrey@baratheon.com"
  },
  {
      "_id": "5e9af93982b4212fc42c4b1a",
      "nombre": "Myrcella",
      "apellidos": "Baratheon",
      "email": "myrcella@baratheon.com"
  },
  {
      "_id": "5e9af95682b4212fc42c4b1b",
      "nombre": "Tommen",
      "apellidos": "Baratheon",
      "email": "tommen@baratheon.com"
  },
  {
      "_id": "5e9af8a382b4212fc42c4b14",
      "nombre": "Tywin",
      "apellidos": "Lannister",
      "email": "tywin@lannister.com"
  }
]
```

Como podemos observar, hemos obtenido la lista de usuarios a los que *Cersei Lannister* sigue.

**3. Todos los usuarios que no sigo**

Esta última consulta hace uso de la misma lógica que usamos para la primera parte: 2 consultas para poder excluir los usuarios a los que sigo.

Podemos hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
Follower.findOne({ follower: id}, (error, follower) => {
  let exclude = [id];
  follower.following.forEach(user => {
    exclude.push(user._id);
  });
  User.find({_id: { $nin: exclude}}, {nombre: 1, apellidos: 1, email: 1}, callback);
});
```

La consulta anterior se hace sobre dos colecciones diferentes, ya que estamos pidiendo la lista de *todos* los usuarios (sean seguidores o no) a los que yo no sigo. El resultado puede verse parecido al siguiente:

```js
"users": [
  {
    "_id": "5e9aeade82b4212fc42c4b0b",
    "nombre": "Sansa",
    "apellidos": "Stark",
    "email": "sansa@stark.com"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5e9af75782b4212fc42c4b0c",
    "nombre": "Arya",
    "apellidos": "Stark",
    "email": "arya@stark.com"
  },
  // ...
  {
    "_id": "5e9af8d882b4212fc42c4b17",
    "nombre": "Tyrion",
    "apellidos": "Lannister",
    "email": "tyrion@lannister.com"
  },
  {
    "_id": "5e9afa2582b4212fc42c4b1f",
    "nombre": "Daenerys",
    "apellidos": "Targaryen",
    "email": "daenerys@targaryen.com"
  }
]
```

Como podemos observar, *Cersei Lannister* sabe muy bien a quién seguir y a quien no.

Espero que esto te haya aclarado un poco más el panorama en cuanto a la forma de modelar tus datos usando Mongoose, y sobre todo aprovechar los métodos que tiene disponibles para tareas ritunarias, sin necesidad de llegar a complicarnos la vida con procesos de agregación.

Comment: Wow, la lógica que usas es realmente envidiable, me arrepiento de no haberle puesto recompensa a mi pregunta y no haberte dado todos mis puntos de reputación aunque sean muy pocos ya que no hace mucho que conozco este sitio, la verdad que es muy buena tu lógica a la hora de manejas datos, ahora yo me pregunto, esta misma lógica de introducir documentos dentro de otro documento puede ser factible a la hora de crear un sistema de notificaciones? que tengas muy buenos días y muchísimas gracias de verdad por esta maravillosa solución que me diste

Comment: Depende de lo que necesites, puedes crear estructuras de datos bastante complejas según tu aplicación lo requiera. Un sistema de notificaciones no es tan complejo, pero se me ocurre que puedes anidar documentos en una lista tal como lo hago con la lista de seguidores. Por otro lado, si la respuesta es válida, basta con aceptarla como tal. Saludos

Comment: muchísimas gracias por tu tiempo, me sirvió de mucho y aprendí mucho aunque no lo creas, que tengas buen día

Comment: una ultima pregunta, me indicaste que a cada documento yo puedo agregar un array que contien un objeto con datos, en el primer ejemplo vos agregaste un `type` que contiene un `ObjetId` y un ref que apunta al documento usuarios, yo puedo agregar datos adicionales en ese objeto? como por ejemplo un nombre o un apellido, osea un dato que yo quiera, puedo hacerlo? como seria la forma correcta?

Comment: No es recomendable que agregues info adicional en documentos referenciados, ya que cuando traigas los datos, puedes confundir esa información adicional con la que se almacena en el documento original. Las referencias sirven precisamente para eso: enlazar documentos de la misma colección o de una colección diferente, sin alterar los datos presentes en el documento original.